# How to check for a nil value of an object before execution of code in corona sdk at enter frame event

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I want to remove an object from a group whose age  has increased to 20 seconds, Objects are created after 20 seconds from the time of starting the game, so it shows error of nil value at game loop, i want to know how to check for a nil object because here game loop is executed before the object creation, please try to solve the problem. thanks...

Below is the code:

```
    function createobject(event)
        local object=display.newImage("obj1.png")
        object.x=500
        object.y=600
        object.GeneratedTime=event.time/1000
        group:insert( object )
    end

    function showobj(event)
        createobject(event)
    end
        timer.performWithDelay(8000, showobj, 0)

        function gameloop(event)
             if group~=nil then
                for i=1,group.numChildren do
                         local child = group[i]
                         local age= event.time/100-child[i].GeneratedTime
                         if age>20 then
                         child.parent:remove( child[i] )
                         end
                end
             end
        end

        Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", gameloop )
```

Comment: Your description is not clear. Try to be more specific and post the error messages you are getting. And please fix the indentation of your code to match the nesting level of your definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(child[i]~=nil)then    -- You can check for the existence of child as this --
  local age= event.time/100-child[i].GeneratedTime
  if age>20 then
    child.parent:remove( child[i] )
  end
end
```

Keep Coding......... :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with corona yet, But If you're just going to check that object exists or not, As i can see you got event on arg 1 of show obj function and you said It just gives nil after timer has passed. So the best way to check If your object Is nil or not, Is below:

```
function showobj(event)
   if event == nil then return end
   createobject(event)
end
```